# cin.get with escape character

Tags: c++, cin

I have code using `cin.get( input, c )` where `c` is the delimiter character. It fails on rare occasions because there is another character e used as an escape. So, if `c` follows e, I want `cin.get` to go to the next `c`, not the escaped `c`.

I am currently checking to see if the last character from `cin.get` is e and, if so, append another `cin.get`. Is there a way to add an escape character to `cin.get` so I don't need the extra check for the escape character?

Comment: You mean you want to read a character, and if it's a backslash then read another character and convert those two characters to a C++ character escape code? If that's the case, then no you can't do that. At least not with a single `get` call, you need two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want behavior like this, you'll need to implement it yourself. It's not built into to `cin.get`.

At least in theory, the iostreams library does provide a place it would be sort of reasonable to plug in this sort of logic, so it would act like part of the stream. Specifically, an iostream has an associated `locale`, and uses the locale's `codecvt` facet to convert from the external representations of characters in the file to the internal representation of characters as they'll be seen by your program. You *could* do this conversion in a custom `codecvt` facet.

That has a fairly significant problem though -- writing a `codecvt` facet is fairly painful. Trying to write this conversion as a codecvt facet instead of doing the job after reading is like to roughly double the amount of code, and at least triple the amount of difficulty involved.

That investment *can* pay off -- packaging the conversion into a `codecvt` facet can make it somewhat easier to integrate into multiple programs. If you really expect to use this particular conversion across many programs, packaging it into a facet might make sense. If (as I'd guess is the case here) you're unlikely to use it in other programs, it's *probably* not worth the trouble.